# Coffee machine wiring diagram

Tags: switches, raspberry-pi

First of all I am a beginner in electronics / electricity. I am currently trying to connect a coffee machine to a Raspberry Pi powered relay.

No problem with that, but as I am going to put apart and rewire a coffee machine, pretty dangerous heating device after all, I wanted to fully understand its wiring diagram beforehand.

That's where I'm stuck. This is the diagram I drew of it.

[image: coffee machine wiring diagram]

I could understand that the three pin device in the middle is a rocker switch. The thing I don't get is the use of the third pin in such a device. What if there were only two pins int the switch, and the wires connected to the upper right one were just fixed together ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably an illuminated switch so the top-right pin provides a path for the lamp and a convenient tie point for the appliance manufacturer.

Comment: Is the switch lit?

Comment: It actually is an illuminated switch. I still don't get one thing : when the switch is lit off, i.e. the left and the top-right pin are connected, isn't there some kind of short circuit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's most likely a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fikSGU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to this design, the light will be on, whether the thermostat is on or of (if it exists in the circuit)

So yes, shorting the right terminals would give a nice short circuit.

I've also seen switches with four terminals. Two for a pure switch, and two for a pure light.

Comment: After some thinking, and doing some more testing, I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

The normally open side of the relay is thermostatically pulled down to the closed contact position to allow current to the hot plate / brewer element; then when the t-stat opens, the n/c side of the relay completes the circuit to the green light that lets you know that the brew is ready.